# Return class destructor

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I'm a student and I'm learning C++. I quite good at C++ still "simple" things get me entangled. I've recently learn classes, methods, constructor/deconstructor, inheritance, virtual, etc. I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test {
    int a, c;
public:
    test() { cout << "Constructor\n"; }
    test(int a) :a(a) { cout<<"Explicit Constructor\n"; }
    test foo(const test&, const test&);
    ~test() { cout << "DECONSTRUCTOR!\n"; }
};

test test::foo(const test &t1, const test &t2) {
    test rez;
    rez.c = t1.a + t2.a;
    return rez;
}

void main() {
    test t1(5), t2(21), rez;
    rez.foo(t1, t2);
    cin.ignore();
}
```

I know that in foo I create a local class that is deleted when out of scope. So when foo is called I should see one constructor and one destructor, but it gives me one more deconstructor, so I have one constructor for two destructors.

Comment: You need to have the copy constructor print as well.

Comment: Just a FYI: The constructor taking a single `int` argument, it isn't actually *explicit* using C++ terminology.

Comment: I'm going to let someone else give a definitive answer, but I'm fairly sure what you are seeing is `rez` inside `test::foo` being destroyed, and then the return value of `rez.foo(t1, t2)` being destroyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more method to your `class test`:

```
test(test const &) { cout << "Copy constructor" << endl; }
```

See what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to implement the copy constructor:

```
test(const test &rhs)
{
  cout << "Constructor";
}
```

It's being used to copy the `rez` object back to the caller of `foo`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to comments:

```
test test::foo(const test &t1, const test &t2) {
    test rez;
    // constructor for rez invoked
    rez.c = t1.a + t2.a;
    return rez;
    // destructor for rez invoked
}

void main() {
    test t1(5), t2(21), rez;
    // 3 constructor invocations
    rez.foo(t1, t2);
    // constructor for return value is called
    // but you are missing it since you did not implement copy constructor
    // destructor for return value is called
    // as you did not use it
    cin.ignore();
    // 3 destructor invocations
}
```